# How to identify and remove CBC ciphers in the CipherSuite?

Tags: encryption, openssl, rsa, tls1.2, cbc-mode

I have apache http server with below ciphers in the cipherSuite. After a scan I found some of the ciphers(CBC) are weak and need to be removed. But I am unable to identify which of them are actually CBC. Can you please help?

FYI -
Versions are

Apache 2.4.23; openssl 1.0.2h; RHEL7

**SSLCipherSuite:**

*ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:
AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES:DES-CBC3-SHA:
!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:
!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!3DES*

**CBC ciphers causing vulnerability: How to identify these in above suite?**
*       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A*

I found some ciphers with "CBC3", but when I remove them Apache is not responding for https requests.

Comment: DES-CBC3-SHA  is TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA.

Comment: Ok. But When I remove "DES-CBC3-SHA" apache is not responding for any https requests. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I see there's a cipher "AES" between AES256-SHA256 and DES-CBC3-SHA is this correct or part of the problem? (btw I have almost no experience in this area.)

Answer (score 5):

Any cipher with `CBC` in the name is a CBC cipher and can be removed. For improved security, you should also sort the ciphers from strongest to weakest and set `SSLHonorCipherOrder on` and `SSLProtocol all -SSLv3` in your config.

Mozilla has a neat tool for generating secure webserver configurations that you might find useful, notably the [modern cipher suite](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=apache-2.4.23&openssl=1.0.2h&hsts=yes&profile=modern) configuration for your Apache and OpenSSL version. After that, try the [Qualsys SSL Labs Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) to see how you did.

Comment: Thanks for the Mozilla link. It's nice to have examples in that syntax, very few are out there on the web that I found..